# How to set up critsend for my domain

Tags: php, email, dns, smtp, gmail

I'm trying to improve email delivery from my domains. I'm using Gmail servers(Gmail MX records).

Recently I've subscribed to critsend. I've successfully used its API to send mails from phpmailer.

Now I need all the outgoing mails from my domain to use critsend services. Critsend documentation specifies this SMTP setup information:

```
Server: smtp.critsend.com
Port: 25 or 587
Username: [your CritSend username]
Password: [your CritSend password]
Encryption: Plain Text
```

Where should I add these details? In exim?
If I use critsend services will it conflict with Gmail servers?

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'Now I need all the outgoing mails from my domain to use critsend services'.

Comment: i have several email addresses - abc@mydomain.com, xyz@mydomain.com. I want the outgoing mails to be relayed through critsend server. How do I do it?

Comment: I wanted to know if you want these settings to be used for a specific script. I don't know how you're hosting the site. You might own the server and want all mail the server could send to relay through this one service. A code example from your Script would be helpful too. I always lean toward the PEAR Mail library. Works well for SMTP.